# Git revert revert or what?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have problem with our git repo. I had *feature* branch and merged it into *release* branch. After some time I reverted *feature* (additional 'revert' commit added).

Now, in Pull requests if I want to merge my *feature* to *release*, I don't see any changes, beside those I added recently!

So, revert commit reverts my changes on merge with *release*. How to apply my changes above this revert commit?

Answer (score 0):

In git Revert is a commit. So if you still need the change from your commit - leave it as is and go ahead with merge. If you don't need them - revert your revert. The good point is you can revert the revert of revert if necessary.